# ReactNative app could vibrate in background when push notification is received but native iOS app(Swift) could not vibrate in background

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, vibration

I have two apps, one in react-native(RN) and other in native iOS (Swift). Apps are related to video call and it shows push notification when any video call request is received. Device should ring and vibrate when it gets push notification.

In RN app, I could use Vibrate function and set timeout for it. When device receive push notification device could be locked or unlocked and app could be in background or killed. Device keeps ringing and vibrating till the timeout in above cases. That is working fine for me.

In Swift app, device should do the same as I mentioned above. I use this one function to vibrate the device. `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))` and other function I know is this `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))`. When I use any of these two functions for background vibration, it does not work. It only works when app is in foreground. I also want device to vibrate multiple times so I tried with timer and that also does not work when app is in background.

My question is if RN can make vibrate work in background, how can I do it in Swift? I checked code of RN-Vibrate module and it does not do anything special. It uses JS setTimeout function to call iOS vibrate function and make device vibrate. You can set pattern and cancel it anytime. Pattern and timeout works in background too. This works when app is in background or killed and device is locked or unlocked.

Any one has any idea about it? How to do in Swift?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since iOS 13, push notifications, especially VoIP pushes, have changed. Make sure the push is received at all. Plus you need entitlements to do anything in the background.

Comment: Remember that NSLog appears in the console log, so you have at least some way to debug your code. "Swift cannot" is of course a wrong assumption, and "why Swift cannot" would be useless to you. You are doing it wrong, and your question is "how do I do it right".

Comment: I receive push notification and also have entitlements and required background mode set for it. NSLog appears in console but it does not vibrate.